# HTML, CSS and javascript editor with tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I have for now :

http://jsfiddle.net/W29Wk/

(I'm using Dreamweaver with the Spry Tabbed panels)

I'd like to make something similar to JSFiddle, when you share the script...
What I need is to be able to write my HTML code in the first tab, CSS in the second and Javascript in the third one. Once I'm done, I go in the "RESULT" tab and it renders my code into HTML.

The RESULT tab does not need to be a TextArea, it can be a DIV or a iFrame, as long as it is the same size of the other TextArea.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which part of the task is the problem? To create editors or to display results?

Comment: It s to display the HTML rendered result in the last tab. It need to take the first 3 tabs, combine them to make the full code, and be render it into HTML in the last tab. Sorry for my english! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The result needs to be an iFrame. Jeffrey Way explained it very good in this screencast on nettuts+: [How to Inject Custom HTML and CSS into an iframe](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe/)

You can make the tabs tabs yourself (or just google it).

But why are you making a second [tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/)?